# Do the Knights of Zakuul fall to the the Dark Side?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the MMORPG *Star Wars: The Old Republic (2011)* a new order of Force users was introduced. They first appeared in the expansion pack *Knights of the Fallen Empire (2015)*

This order was named the Knights of Zakuul and served as protectors of the Emperor of Zakuul, known as Valkorion.

See: *http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Zakuul*

The in-game codex describes them as such:

> Before Zakuulans served the Immortal Emperor, they lived in nomadic
>   tribes, each led by three Force sensitives: Matriarch, Champion and
>   High Shaman. After Valkorion had united the tribes, he repurposed
>   these roles to form the Knights of Zakuul. Officially considered
>   protectors of the people, Knights hunt down corruption in the Eternal
>   Empire. In actuality, they are enforcers of the Emperor's will and
>   fanatical in their adoration for Valkorion and his family. Zakuul
>   Knights don't limit themselves to studying one side of the Force,
>   instead teaching balance and exploration. Knights have their own
>   relationships with the Force, but are encouraged to share their
>   findings with the rest of the order. No area is deemed "weak" or "a
>   dangerous path"--they are all parts of a larger, limitless power.
>   Ultimately, every action a Knight takes is to honor the Immortal
>   Emperor. Sacrifices, whether material or a life, are essential to show
>   one's commitment to the Emperor.

Found at https://swtor.jedipedia.net/en/cdx/knights-of-zakuul

This summary of the Knights describes them as balanced Force users, neither fully light, nor fully dark. They seem to be driven only by their desire to serve the royal family.

They are, however, not obsessed with their tasks alone. They do have lives outside of their worksphere.

For example

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Balisk: He has a husband and, if spared by the player, sends a note to thank the player.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Novo: He is hit hard by the death of his partner and seeks vengeance, but is not consumed by it and is able to overcome it after being spared.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Senya_Tirall: She makes a clear distinction between her work as a Knight and her social life. She seems to actually consider it a job/career.

> "Being a Knight means everything, but I don't let it define me. When
>   it's time to go to work, I'm who I need to be. The rest of the time,
>   I'm just myself."

The Knights of Zakuul seem quite good at maintaining a balance. While playing the game I had the impression to be fighting a loyal police force that was just following orders.

**The question:** Do the Knights of Zakuul ever fully fall to the Dark Side and why or, if not, why not?

Comment: Are you asking if they fall as a *whole*, or if any *individual* knights ever go to the Dark Side?

Comment: I more interested in the individual Knight. Individual Jedi fall to the Dark side, but I saw no example of that with the Knights of Zakuul during my playthrough. I was therefore curious if anyone had any proof of certain Knights falling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Knights of Zakuul were never really placed in as main characters in the expansions. Senya is the only Knight with an active role throughout the entire expansion(depending on the choices you make) and she clearly had not fallen. You do see the 2 knights you mentioned earlier, Novo and Basilisk, briefly, in like Chapter 3 of the KOTFE expansion, but that's it. There are no other knights that affect the storyline significantly as of yet. The only place where that might happen is in a fanfiction or something.

That being said, it is revealed throughout the storyline that after Valkorion was killed, Prince Arcann had the Knights of Zakuul kill/ eradicate the Scions of Zakuul. While the argument could be made that they were just following orders, there were many Knights who followed Senya after Arcann came to power and left the Eternal Empire because they saw how wrong the Empire had become. Zakuul Knights had the choice to leave or stay and help Arcanns regime, and some stayed. So yes, I'd say they can be corrupted and made to serve the Dark Side.

Comment: Well argumented, the defecting Knights you refer to were probably the ones killed here: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ord_Mantell_massacre. They might indeed be more lightsided than the ones still supporting Vaylin and Arcann.